# How do you populate ORGANIZATIONNAME in an Xcode IDETemplateMacro.plist file header template?

Tags: xcode, plist

I am trying to create a custom file header template that generates a single line copyright message but am not able to get my organisation name to populate.

I have tried a variety of text macros defined in [Xcode Help's Text macros reference](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev7fe737ce0). `DATE`, `YEAR`, and `FULLUSERNAME` work as expected however `ORGANIZATIONNAME` and `COPYRIGHT` are not populated for me.

I have tried placing the IDETemplateMacros.plist in:

- `<ProjectName>.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/`
- `<WorkspaceName>.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/`
- `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/`

My organisation name is set in the Xcode 10.3 project.

When I add:

```
  Copyright (c) ___YEAR___ ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___. All rights reserved.
```

to the IDETemplateMacros.plist the generated file header is:

```
  // Copyright © 2019 ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___. All rights reserved.
```

rather than the expected:

```
  // Copyright © 2019 MyOrganisationName. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: And the organisation name was set when you created the project in Xcode?

Comment: Yes. I just created a new project to see if the same behaviour could be observed and it worked as expected too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `ORGANIZATIONNAME` and `COPYRIGHT` the IDETemplateMacros.plist must be in:

`<ProjectName>.xcodeproj/<UserName>xcuserdatad/`

Comment: In my testing on Xcode 11, it worked in either of the locations related to the project bundle or workspace bundle, but failed in the library folder.  It may be ORGANIZATIONNAME is not available to a template in the library folder.  And docs say that COPYRIGHT will expand to blank if the company name is not set.